# Error while migrating data from On Prem server to Azure DB using Database migration service (DMS)

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, data-migration

I am new to azure migration services. My end goal is to migrate On Prem database to Azure DB using Azure database migration service. While setting up migration service I faced below error. Please find attached screenshot of error.
Let me know if anyone have idea on this. [Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57Nht.png)

```
Error type
Database migration error
Error Detail
Collector 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Migration.Core.Collectors.SqlLOBCountsCollector' failed to collect data.
An item with the same key has already been added.
```

Comment: The error seems like it's duplicating data somewhere (whether on purpose or not). Did you use DMS to migrate the schema? I would do a schema compare of your Premises database and your Azure SQL database to make sure they're the same.

Comment: Thanks for your response. First I used DMS to migrate schema and it was successfully migrated. Here note that my target database (Azure) is totally empty, so there is no chance to duplicating data on target server.